What is it called when someone does not know their purpose in life?
what is it called when someone does not know their true purpose or role in life?

I think you'll find it's called "normality".

There are many words that could express that. Can you give the sentence where you would use the term?

It's one hell of an achievement. Somebody's been telling you what you should do since day one.

It depends. Shiftless is an adjective that means lazy and not having much determination or a clear purpose (Cambridge).

@PhilSweet - Many people will indeed tell you how and what to do, based on their own experiences and agenda.  But what they tell you doesn't necessarily comport with your own personal feeling and motivation. Millions of people end up 'finding themselves' in a field or occupation far removed from what they've "been told what they SHOULD do" and were adrift until they "found themselves" on a personal level doing something else entirely.

AHD has adrift in that sense:
AHD adrift

Without direction or purpose:
"The report is about people in their twenties and how alienated and adrift they feel" (Tom Shales).


One term you can use is

aimless
without any clear intentions, purpose, or direction

From Cambridge Dictionary, and Merriam-Webster has

aimless
without aim or purpose : not having a goal or purpose


Opting for a figurative manner of saying that, one could use "rudderless".

(Collins) rudderless adjective
A country or a person that is rudderless does not have a clear aim or a strong leader to follow.

The country was politically rudderless for almost three months.
...a feeling in the country that the Government was drifting rudderless.


(Andy Kaufman Revealed!: Best Friend Tells All - Bob Zmuda · 2000) For Andy such rejection was tantamount to a Roman Catholic being excommunicated. Suddenly he was rudderless, cast adrift by his own religion at the lowest point in his life.
(Growing Up - Frank C. Strasburger · 2012
) Until the shot, nothing in Josh's life was compelling; he was rudderless. The illusion that all things were possible paralyzed him—he had no idea which way to turn, and it didn't seem to matter. His work for the suicide hotline gave him, for the first time, a sense of direction, a cause that fully engaged him.
